# Transit visa for 11-hour layover in Belgian airport for a connecting flight

Tags: visas

I booked a flight to Riga and it has an 11-hour layover in a Belgian airport.
Do I need a transit visa?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do I need a visa to transit (or layover) in the Schengen area?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30569/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-or-layover-in-the-schengen-area)

Comment: No, you use your Latvian visa to enter Schengen in Belgium

Answer (score 1):

No, because Latvia and Belgium are both in the Schengen area, which you will enter in Belgium using your Latvian visa.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schengen_Area for more information.